# How does Spark read 100K images effeciently?

Tags: image, machine-learning, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Currently, I'm programming something on image classification with Spark. I need to read all the images into memory as RDD and my method is as following:

```
val images = spark.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://imag-dir/")
```

**imag-dir** is the target image storing directory on hdfs. With this method, all the images will be   loaded into memory and every image will be organized as "image name, image content" pair. However, I find this process is time consuming, is there any better way to load large image data set into spark?

Comment: Try putting the data on a RAMdisk or SSD to see if the time is used in I/O or processing so you have a better idea what issue needs addressing. Are you already multi-threaded and do you run on multi-core/multi-CPU systems? http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-use-multi-thread-in-RDD-map-function-td15286.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, the program is multi-threaded. I think I/O is a good point to optimize and I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that may be because you have a lot of *small* files on HDFS, which is a problem as such (the 'small files problem'). [Here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) you'll find a few suggestions in addressing the issue.

You may also want to set the number of partitions (the `minpartitions` argument of `wholetextFiles`) to a reasonable number : at least 2x the number of cores in your cluster (look [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmL0N3qfSc8) for details).

But in sum, apart from the 2 ideas above, the way you're loading those is ok and *not* where your problem lies (assuming `spark` is your Spark context).